# Trap execution order in bash

Tags: bash

Let's consider the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo EXIT' EXIT
trap 'echo ERR' ERR

false
```

How can I know order of execution of traps? It easy to rut the script and check it out but I can't find anything in documentation. Have you seen something?

Comment: They will be executed in the order registered events take place. Why do you need documentation for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @oguz_ismail suggested, the order is the same order the events occur.

For example, if you manage `SIGINT` and `EXIT` as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

__die() { :;}
__ctrl_c() { :;}

trap __die EXIT
trap __ctrl_c INT
```

In case of `SIGINT` ( E.G. `C-c` pressed or `kill -2 "${pid}"`), you will always have `__ctrl_c` executed before `__die` (unless you force it otherwise).

As a best practice I usually resend the signal:

```
#!/bin/bash

__ctrl_c() {
  printf "%b" "\n" >&2
  printf "Interrupted by user ):\n"
  # Avoid looping deleting trap
  trap 2
  # Resend sigint
  kill -2 "$$"
}

trap __ctrl_c INT
```

You can see a list of signals with `trap -l` (at least from bash 5) or `kill -l`.

If you need some specific "pattern" to follow with traps, you can force a signal with `kill -signal $$`.

For example, in `__ctrl_c` you could send `kill -15 $$` to call `SIGTERM`

You can read signal(7) and sigaction(2) for more infos.